# Android, Screen capture

Tags: android, android-ndk, adb

I am building an app that should implement screen ~mirroring~ for any **un-rooted** device having Android 4 and above, 2 frames / sec will suffice for start.

I am trying to use the ADB "framebuffer:" command to grab device screen shots

The ADB USB communication protocol is message oriented ( not streaming ), thus, to get a chunk of data a set of read(A_WRTE@4096bytes) / confirm(A_OKEY@24bytes) command pairs are received/sent.
 As long as the receiving side didn't send the A_OKEY no additional data will be pushed by the device ( hence, not a streaming protocol ).

In order to optimize performance I have implemented the ADB USB protocol directly rather than using ADB.exe

The image of a Samsung Galaxy 5 device is of a resolution of 1920*1080 and 32 bit-depth, and thus, RAW framebuffer image would weight 1920*1080*4=8294400 bytes ( for iPADs it would even be bigger ), using the "framebuffer:" command over the ADB message oriented protocol it takes ~2 seconds to receive a single screen-shot ( grrr.. ).

If this would have been a streaming protocol it should have taken ~150 msec on USB 2.0 @ 480Mbps

- Having the above in mind, is there any way to get the "framebuffer:"s faster?
- Is there any way to reduce the resolution before sending over USB?
- Is there any other approach, common to all devices, to take a screenshots, 24x7 in a faster manner ?
- An AirPlay equivalent for Android ( **COMMON to all devices** ) would be optimal ?

**P.S.**
I have already tried the ASL project, it doesn't work on my "Samsung Galaxy 5" since ADB.exe shell is not running with system privileges ( rather, it runs under the 'shell' account ).

Comment: adbd runs as "shell" on all unhacked stock Android releases.  But shell should be able to capture screenshots - that's how the button in DDMS is able to work on production devices.

Comment: I get "Permission denied" for open("/dev/graphics/fb0", O_RDONLY) under the shell account...

Comment: That hasn't been how you've been supposed to capture the screen in years - even if you could open it, it won't work on most devices with a GPU.

Comment: That is how it is implemented @ the "ASL Project", and uat the screencap toll provided with android OS ( as of 2010... )
... how should I implement it then ?

Comment: You must be looking at something very old then.  ADBD has used /system/bin/screencap to do the capture since around September 2010: https://github.com/android/platform_system_core/blob/master/adb/framebuffer_service.c  Newer releases have builtin compressed screen recording, too.

Comment: Yeah, This is worth trying though "screencap" will be executed numerous times per second... is there any other option to directly read framebuffers ?

Comment: It might not yield a great boost of performance, but you can try to either reducing the resolution to, say, 720p, and/or compressing the image to jpeg or other format. Just by compressing you should be able to cut the time by half or more, depending on how long it will take to perform the compression.

Comment: One of the recent Nexus devices (4? 5? can't remember) was taking about 500ms to compress a 720p frame with libpng.  You'd probably get much better results from VNC-style inter-frame differential compression since consecutive frames will often have few changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Android 4.3 and later you can do what `screenrecord` does and feed a mirrored virtual display into the video encoder.  [Version 1.2](http://bigflake.com/screenrecord/), which ships with 5.0 "Lollipop", has a streaming-over-USB feature built in, including the termio code to send binary data across `adb shell`.  Use the "hidden" argument `--output-format=h264` and specify a hyphen (`-`) as the output filename.

Source code is in [frameworks/av/cmds/screenrecord](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/av/+/lollipop-release/cmds/screenrecord/).

This is the only way to get decent frame rates over USB.  You can experiment with uncompressed data by specifying `--output-format=raw-frames`, but even at VGA resolution you'll have trouble getting frames across at a decent speed.

FWIW, current devices don't generally use a frame buffer dev, except perhaps in recovery mode.  Instead they use overlays that are combined by the hardware composer as the display is scanned out.  Full details are in the [architecture doc](https://source.android.com/devices/graphics/architecture.html).

Comment: Thanks for your detailed response, I need this to work on 4.3, screenrecord is limited to a recording session of a maximum duration of 3 minutes, I need this to run ~24x7, is it possible to access the same service used for chromecast mirroring through an adb session ?

Comment: The screenrecord *binary* requires Android 4.4 and is limited to 3 minutes.  The screenrecord 1.0 *source* will build (with one minor tweak) on Android 4.3, and you can remove the 3-minute limit.  (You could also binary-edit the executable if you have that knowledge set.)  The program uses internal APIs, so you can't reliably use a single binary across different devices and releases, but there's no public API equivalent in 4.3.  I don't know much about ChromeCast, so I can't speak to that.

Comment: Fadden, Isn't the executable signed by the OS vendor key? isn't this signing req to access screen capture functionality?
Will recompiling the source or patching the binary actually work having in mind it's not signed w/ the vendor key ?

Comment: The executable is not signed, and does not need to be.  Access to virtual displays is controlled by the usual security mechanisms (i.e. you must be "shell" or "root" user) to prevent apps from doing nefarious things.

Comment: @darkyen00: it's not built-in, but you could write a filter that captured stdout from screenrecord and sent it across a TCP connection.